# Numerical evaluation of Green function to evolve wavefunction for harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, greens-functions, propagator, software

Inspired by the paper "[Feynman's derivation of the Schrodinger equation](http://www.physics.utah.edu/%7Estarykh/phys7640/Lectures/FeynmansDerivation.pdf)", I'm trying to do a simple numerical evaluation of the following equation (4.1) from the paper:

$$ \psi (x,t_2) = \int dy \, G(x,y) \psi(y,t_1), \tag{4.1}$$

with $t_2 > t_1$. This equation says the wavefunction $\psi$ evolves under the effect of the Green's function $G$.

Equation (4.11) from the paper says that

$$ G=\sqrt \frac{m}{2\pi i \hbar \epsilon} e^{iS/\hbar} .\tag{4.11}$$ The paper integrates the action $S$ over an infinitesimal time $\Delta t = \epsilon$.

So, plugging things in, I follow the paper (or equation 2.19 of [these lecture notes](https://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Services/Class/PHYS480/qm_PDF/chp2.pdf)) and write my infinitesimal action as

$$ S = \frac{1}{2}m \frac{(x-y)^2}{\epsilon} - U\left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right)\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}m \frac{(x-y)^2}{\epsilon} - \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 \left(\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\right)\epsilon ;$$

the second equality comes from subbing in the potential for the harmonic oscillator.

My reasoning is that we should be able to discretize this on a lattice and get an approximately correct answer.  So, I'm treating the above integration as a matrix multiplication, where $\psi(y,t_1)$ and $\psi(x,t_2)$ are vectors, and $G(x,y)$ is a matrix. (The integration over $y$ is the matrix rows dotted into the wavefunction vector, and then each matrix row produces a different value of $x$.)

This is analogous to a single step of Feynman's path integral. The infinitesimal $G$ calculated here is (if I understand correctly) the same as the transfer matrix $T$ in lattice gauge theory.

Below is my MATLAB code:

```
%% Part 0: Initialization and constants
c=299792458; % m/s <= speed of light
qe=1.60217657e-19; % C <= fundamental/electron charge
me=9.10938291e-31; % kg <= mass of electron
hb=1.05457173e-34; % kg m^2/s <= hbar Plank constant div by 2pi
m=me; % mass of particle in oscillator
dimX=1000; % dimension of lattice
dx=1e-10; % lattice x spacing
dt=1e-15; % time step
x=linspace((-dimX/2)*dx,(dimX/2-1)*dx,dimX); % lattice x points
omega=9e12; % oscillator frequency
% analytic results 
xi=@(x) sqrt(m*omega/hb)*x;
hoNorm=(m*omega/(pi*hb))^(1/4); % ho wavefunction normalization factor
hoPsi0=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^0*factorial(0))*1.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).'; % the first 4 analytic ho wavefunctions
hoPsi1=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^1*factorial(1))*2*xi(x).'.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).';
hoPsi2=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^2*factorial(2))*(4*xi(x).^2-2).'.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).';
hoPsi3=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^3*factorial(3))*(8*xi(x).^3-12*xi(x)).'.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).';
hoEn=@(n) (1/2+n)*hb*omega;

%% Part 1: Generate the propagator matrix
% harmonic oscillator Lagrangian = 1/2 m v^2 - 1/2 m omega^2 x^2
[Y,X]=meshgrid(x,x);
G=arrayfun(@(xx,yy) sqrt(m/(2*pi*1i*hb*dt))*exp(1i/hb* ( 1/2*m*(xx-yy)^2/dt-1/2*m*omega^2* (1/2*(xx+yy))^2 *dt ) ), X, Y);
figure;
imagesc(x,x,angle(G))
%imagesc(x,x,unwrap(angle(G)))
colorbar;

%% Part 2: Compare analytic solution for harmonic oscillator to Green function e^iS/\hbar method

origWf=hoPsi1; % the starting point; choose whatever you'd like here
GpropWf=origWf; % the wavefunction we'll propagate using the Green function below
figure;

for n=1:10 % whatever number of steps you'd like to visualize
             % for analytic part can be 1000 or more
    ts=dt*(n-1);
    origWfTs=hoPsi1*exp(-1i/hb*hoEn(1)*ts); % time stepped analytic solution
                                            %  (match this to the one you constructed above at t=0)

    plot(x,real(origWfTs)); % plot timestepped analytic solution
    hold on;
    plot(x,imag(origWfTs));

    GpropWf=G*GpropWf; % evolve and plot the Green function solution
    plot(x,real(GpropWf)); % feel free to turn off this part and check if 
    plot(x,imag(GpropWf)); %   the analytic solution looks right by itself
    hold off
    legend('real(origWfTs) - analytic','imag(origWfTs) - analytic','real(GpropWf) - numerical Green','imag(GpropWf) - numerical Green');
    pause(1/100); % pause so you can see it
end
```

The punch line is this: it doesn't work. I don't know if it's something fundamental in the math or a problem in my code, but the script does *not* generate the proper time-stepping to match the analytic solutions. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the above code *does* work, but only for certain values of $dt$ and $dx$. Also, the normalization is a mystery to me; I just put in a value that makes the analytic curves match the curves generated by propagator $G$ time evolution. I'm going to open a [new question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/605289/numerical-evaluation-of-green-function-to-evolve-wavefunction-for-harmonic-oscil) to ask for help on these points, but will post the working code here; to me it is quite beautiful to see the classical-quantum connection so simply.

```
%% Part 0: Initialization and constants
c=299792458; % m/s <= speed of light
qe=1.60217657e-19; % C <= fundamental/electron charge
me=9.10938291e-31; % kg <= mass of electron
hb=1.05457173e-34; % kg m^2/s <= hbar Plank constant div by 2pi
m=me; % mass of particle in oscillator
dimX=1000; % dimension of lattice
dx=0.05*1e-9; % lattice x spacing
dt=1.5e-14; % time step
x=linspace((-dimX/2)*dx,(dimX/2-1)*dx,dimX); % lattice x points
omega=9e12; % oscillator frequency
% analytic results 
xi=@(x) sqrt(m*omega/hb)*x;
hoNorm=(m*omega/(pi*hb))^(1/4); % ho wavefunction normalization factor
hoPsi0=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^0*factorial(0))*1.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).'; % the first 4 analytic ho wavefunctions
hoPsi1=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^1*factorial(1))*2*xi(x).'.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).';
hoPsi2=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^2*factorial(2))*(4*xi(x).^2-2).'.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).';
hoPsi3=hoNorm*1/sqrt(2^3*factorial(3))*(8*xi(x).^3-12*xi(x)).'.*exp(-xi(x).^2/2).';
hoEn=@(n) (1/2+n)*hb*omega;

%% Part 1: Generate the propagator matrix
% harmonic oscillator Lagrangian = 1/2 m v^2 - 1/2 m omega^2 x^2
[Y,X]=meshgrid(x,x);
G=arrayfun(@(xx,yy) 5.0115e-11*sqrt(m/(2*pi*1i*hb*dt))*exp(1i/hb* ( 1/2*m*(xx-yy)^2/dt-1/2*m*omega^2* (1/2*(xx+yy))^2 *dt ) ), X, Y);
figure;
imagesc(x,x,angle(G))
%imagesc(x,x,unwrap(angle(G)))
colorbar;
drawnow;

%% Part 2: Compare analytic solution for harmonic oscillator to Green function e^iS/\hbar method

origWf=hoPsi1; % the starting point; choose whatever you'd like here
GpropWf=origWf; % the wavefunction we'll propagate using the Green function below
figure;

for n=1:20 % whatever number of steps you'd like to visualize
             % for analytic part can be 1000 or more
    ts=dt*(n-1);
    origWfTs=hoPsi1*exp(-1i/hb*hoEn(1)*ts); % time stepped analytic solution
                                            %  (match this to the one you constructed above at t=0)

    plot(x,real(origWfTs)); % plot timestepped analytic solution
    hold on;
    plot(x,imag(origWfTs));
    
    plot(x,real(GpropWf)); % % plot the Green function evolved solution
    plot(x,imag(GpropWf));
    hold off
    legend('real(origWfTs) - analytic','imag(origWfTs) - analytic','real(GpropWf) - numerical Green','imag(GpropWf) - numerical Green');

    GpropWf=G*GpropWf; % evolve the Green function solution

    pause(1/100); % pause so you can see it
end
```